# want to spawn mutiple instances of a MovieClip in Action Script 2.0 Flash

Tags: flash, actionscript, actionscript-2, macromedia

I'm quite new to Action Script

I want to create a small game and I need the syntax to create/spawn multiple instances of a movieclip:

- the movieclip is already created in my library
- the movieclip is named "Test" and do I have to pay attention on the instances names
- I work with Macromedia Flash Professional 8

I already tried 
`Test.createEmptyMovieClip();`
but it didn't work

Comment: I tried `attachMovieClip("Test", "newMovieClip1", 0);`, but
I can´t find a usefull description of linkage name, but in my case i got it to work with the dublicate function
`newY`, and `newX` are the offset  
  `var duplicate:MovieClip;  
  var newY:Number = Men._y+130;  
  var newX:Number = Men._x+200;  
  duplicate = Test.duplicateMovieClip("TEST" + i, i,   {_x:newX,_y:newY});`  

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign a linkage name to the movieclip you want to duplicate (google it if you don't know how). Based on that linkage name you can attach several movieclip instances to any existing movieclip like that:

```
attachMovieClip("linkageNameHere", "newMovieClip1", depth);
attachMovieClip("linkageNameHere", "newMovieClip2", depth);
```

or, if you need to attach it to a specific movieclip on your stage:

```
mySpecificMovieClip.attachMovieClip("linkageNameHere", "newMovieClip1", depth);
```